# Texts in Eastern services expressing ideas about the role of woman in child development

Tags: eastern-orthodox, virgin-mary, philosophy, incarnation, biology

I have quite a specific question about the view of ancient Christians on the development of a child. I always assumed, that since the Ephesus Fathers considered being born of human woman as a paramount proof for Christ being truly human, that they must have considered the role of woman as important. On the other hand most ancient natural philosophers tended to diminish the role of woman, claiming that she is only the nurturer of male sperm.

My question is: are there liturgical texts about Theotokos that would somehow reflect the views of contemporary Christians about this? I vaguely remember some mention of the role of blood of Mary, but I can't recollect if it was Octoechos or Menaion and what was exactly stated there.

Comment: What do you mean by "contemporary Christians"? Contemporary to what time period? Also, "ancient Christians" is somewhat vague. What time period do you mean? And you mention child *development,* but the question seems to be more about the woman's role in the *birth* of the child. I voted to leave the question open for now, since there does seem to be the germ of an interesting question here. However, it needs to be be worded more clearly to specify exactly what it is that you're asking. Some references for your background statements would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Octoechos, ec. 7, 9th hirmos of the Sunday canon` (not sure how it is called in English) we can read:

> Слову плоть взаимодавшая

This can be translated as

> lended flesh to the Word

Or, `1st troparion of Theotokos Sunday canon, ec. 5`:

> От чистых кровей Твоих усырися плоть преестественно

That is:

> From pure bloods of Yours, densed the flesh (of Christ) supernaturally

In the last troparion of the Canon to Eucharist:

> Бог воплотися от чистых кровей твоих

that is

> The God incarnated from pure bloods of yours

And one of my favorite

> внутрь во чреве Твоем плоть исткася
>
> inside the womb of Yours, the flesh (of Christ) en-weaved

There are many other troparions like these in Menaion, but i can't find them so quickly.

In short, the significance of Theotokos' contribution in Christ's development was never underestimated. As well as Mary's own holiness, which can be seen from many other texts.